# can we use different assembly for a particular page?

Tags: asp.net, ajax, reporting-services, .net-assembly

i'm using **Ajax toolkit** 1.0 for my project and **framework 3.5**. i can't update ajax toolkit for project because project is very large. But i want to use **SSRS** for reporting..
But the problem is whenever i build the project it shows error for **system.web.extensions 1.0.61025.0**, but report viewer needs **System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35**, so can i use different assembly for only one page..
Please help with some examples..or suggestions.

Comment: You can't compile a single page for a different .NET version but why can't you upgrade your project to 3.5 keeping everything else untouched (Ajax Toolkit 1.0)? There are not many breaking changes and the only alternative I can imagine (host that single page inside another site) is so terrible that makes me shy...